# Hacer que me de el total de sumar y restar varios inputs jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo la siguiente funcion que lee el subtotal y agrega el inpuesto que esta definido en un input oculto y me da el total, todo eso funciona bien pero quiero agregar descuento y envio para que al ingresarlo en el input correspondiente haga la suma, pero no hace nada, la funcion es esta.

```
function sumar(){
subtotal = 0;
$("#tbventas tbody tr").each(function(){
    subtotal = subtotal + Number($(this).find("td:eq(5)").text());
});
$("input[name=subtotal]").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
porcentaje = $("#impuesto").val();
impuesto = subtotal * (porcentaje/100);
$("input[name=impuesto]").val(impuesto.toFixed(2));
descuento = $("input[name=descuento]").val();
envio = $("input[name=envio]").val();
total = subtotal + impuesto - descuento + envio;
$("input[name=total]").val(total.toFixed(2));

}
```

y los inputs

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="subtotal" readonly="readonly">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="impuesto" readonly="readonly">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="descuento"  >
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="envio" value="0.00" readonly="readonly">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="total" readonly="readonly">
```

la funcion me da bien el valor del subtotal impuesto y total, pero no hace nada cuando ingreso un valor en descuento o envio.
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisa el ejemplo que te pongo acontinuacion:

Explico: El detalle en tus calculos es:

1. Necesitas convertir el string a float, para eso `parseFloat( $("input[name=subtotal]").val())`
2. Validar que el resultado no quede NaN = No a Numeric, osea que tu resultado sea en verdad un numero. `subtotal = isNaN(subtotal) ? 0 : subtotal;`

Despues de eso ya puedes hacer los calculos bien, porque estaba marcando error el `.toFixed` debido a qeu no puede ser aplicado en NaN osea en valores que no son NUMEROS.

```js
$("#sumar").click(function(){
  sumar();
});

function sumar(){
  subtotal = parseFloat( $("input[name=subtotal]").val());//Para convertir el string a FLOAT
  subtotal = isNaN(subtotal) ? 0 : subtotal;  //Valido si quedo en isNaN si es asi lo inicializo en cero, si no tomo el valor ya convertido en float
  console.log('Subtotal: ' + subtotal);
  
  /*
  $("#tbventas tbody tr").each(function(){
      subtotal = subtotal + Number($(this).find("td:eq(5)").text());
  });*/
  
  $("input[name=subtotal]").val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
  porcentaje = parseFloat($("#impuesto").val()); 
  porcentaje = isNaN(porcentaje) ? 0 : porcentaje;//Esta validacion para poder hacer los calculos
  console.log('Porcentaje: ' + porcentaje);
  impuesto = subtotal * (porcentaje/100);
  impuesto = isNaN(impuesto) ? 0 : impuesto;  
  console.log('Impuesto: ' + impuesto);
  //Muestro el impuesto 
  $("input[name=impuesto]").val(impuesto.toFixed(2));
  
  descuento = parseFloat($("input[name=descuento]").val()); 
  descuento = isNaN(descuento) ? 0 : descuento;
  console.log('descuento: ' + descuento);
  
  envio = parseFloat($("input[name=envio]").val()); 
  envio = isNaN(envio) ? 0 : envio;
  console.log('Envio: ' + envio);
  
  total = subtotal + impuesto - descuento + envio;
  //console.log(subtotal + impuesto - descuento + envio);
  $("input[name=total]").val(total.toFixed(2));

}
```

```html
Porcentaje
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" value="25"  id="impuesto" >
<br/><br/><br/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Subtotal
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" value="1000"  name="subtotal" >
<br/>
impuesto
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="impuesto" readonly="readonly">
<br/>
 descuento
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" value="10.00" name="descuento"  >
<br/>
 envio
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" value="100.00" name="envio" value="0.00" readonly="readonly">
<br/>
 total
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="total" readonly="readonly">
 
 
<br/>

<input type="button" value="sumar" id="sumar"/>
```

Comment: Cambie la parte de arriba porque no me daba bien el total, cada vez que cambiaba el descuento o el envio, sumaba el total al que ya habia, si dejo el inicio con subtotal=0; comento las 3 primeras lineas y descomento la que ya tenia si funciona como deseaba utilizando onchange="sumar()" como dijo fabian. Solo una cosa, si el descuento lo quiero manejar con porcentaje como lo haria?

Comment: ya consegui hacerlo con porcentaje el descuento, gracias.

Comment: Que bien :), Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que se actualicen los valores una vez cambies el valor de ciertos inputs, debes ponerles un handler al evento `onchange`

Algo como:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="descuento" onchange="sumar()" >`